# Bootstrap dropdown work after console call

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating template on local machine and don't use webserver for this purpose. In my bootstrap template dropdowns are not work, only after I called from console:

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
```

And now drop down works. Why this happens? Jquery methods works good after page loading, but bootstraps are not.

PS bootstrap.css dropdown.js bootstrap.js jquery.min.js are included and loaded (includes as local files not from cdn)

Comment: make sure ur html follows the bootstrap structure completely - check data-toggles and all to be sure!

Comment: Did you download the template or are building one from scratch?

Comment: Yes, before ask a question I tried with bootstrap examples. Now found the reason, when I'm using bootstrap.js and dropdown.js I have this issue, but when included bootstrap.min.js all works. After I tried bootstrap.js without dropdown.js and it's also works. The problem is that I'm include dropdown.js. bootrstrap.(min.)js has all necessary.

Answer (score 0):

We ran into the same problem, twice.

The first time, we solved it by loading jquery and bootstrap before any other scripts.

The second time, it was because bootstrap.js was being loaded TWICE. We had it once as a script tag, and then again as a requirejs dependency.